# Ruby on Rails / Heroku where are my users emails stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Heroku. I have installed the gem 'Devise' in my RoR app and I use Heroku to deploy my app. The sign up process works fine but where are my users emails stored (the users that sign up for my website)? I want to be able to see/extract a list of all the emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your users and any other database records by running:

```
heroku run rails console
```

from a terminal window. And from there you can run any rails console command as you can on your local machine like `User.all`

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have found useful is to use either the [config variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) or the [Postgres dashboard](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) to get the URL information for the database. I then use that information to construct the JDBC URL for my IDE, RubyMine, to connect to Heroku. As a result, I can view and manipulate the data in all my tables on Heroku from my IDE. You can do something similar for the SQL tool of your choice.